# Update Bootstrap Switch with Leaflet Layer Group

Tags: javascript, leaflet, bootstrap-framework, layer-switcher

I have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s537t380/25/) that shows two example layers that can be toggled on and off using the [Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) to add and remove them from the map; this works fine.

The problem I am having is updating the state of the individual layers switches when the group switch is toggled. As per the example I can create a switch to add the group of layers to the map, however the switches for the individual layers do not update to show the user that is a layer that is effected by the group of layers being added.

I thought this might be possible through the `hasLayer` method but I'm not entirely sure how this would be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line in the `onSwitchChange` event handler of your group switch:

```js
$("[name='my-checkbox2'], [name='my-checkbox3']").bootstrapSwitch('state', state, true);
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s537t380/26/

Reference:

http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/methods.html

> The method `state` can receive an optional third parameter `skip`. if true, `switchChange` event is not executed. The default is false.